# React Native “Only one default export allowed per module” error

Tags: react-native

Good day, I'm using react native. I need to use two exports in a folder, but I get this error when using it. What is the problem?

```
import history from "./components/usrFirst";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class LoginForm extends Component {
...
}
export default withRouter(LoginForm);
export default !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(config) : firebase.app();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you can't have multiple `default` exports. You can have one, and then used a named export for the other.

```
const FirebaseComponent = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(config) : firebase.app();
export {
  FirebaseComponent
}
export default withRouter(LoginForm)
```

Then you would use it like so

```
import LoginForm, { FirebaseComponent } from 'foo.js'
```